# If cell is blank, show value in the another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on two cells, one in **column P** and the other in **column T**. (see the image below).

For the column **P**, I used `=if(REGEXMATCH(I2,"Grade 7"),REPLACE(I2,1,9,""),"")` as a formula so it means that the cell is not empty, right? So, the goal is to have cell T17 return blank when cell P17 has no value or returns as blank.

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already figured it out.

The formula that I used for cell T19: `=IF(P17="","","2021-2022")`